# Как ответить клиенту файлом на Post-запрос. SpringBoot REST API

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, rest

Есть API сервер со SpringBoot. 
Клиент отравляет POST-запрос c Json в теле. Из этого Json сервер создает pdf и этот pdf надо отправить обратно клиенту.

Вот метод принимающий JSON объект от клента, и конвертящий его в pdf. Как вернуть в этом методе файл для клиента? Я понимаю что надо в бинарный вид перевести сначала. Не понимаю как вернуть именно в этом методе. Какой тип возвращаемого значения должен быть?

```
@PostMapping()
    public void createOrder(@RequestBody PaymentOrder order){
        PdfCreater.createPdf(order);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте так написать:

```
@PostMapping()
@ResponseBody
public ResponseEntity<Resource>  createOrder(@RequestBody PaymentOrder order){
    final Resource file = PdfCreater.createPdf(order);
    return ResponseEntity
            .ok()
            .header(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_DISPOSITION, "attachment; filename=\"" + file.getFilename() + "\"")
            .body(file);
}
```

Resource из массива байт можно получить с помощью ByteArrayResource

Comment: Почему используете модификатор static? Можно без него?

Comment: Вроде работает, но в ответе в Postman почему-то приходит "Content-Type →application/json", а не "binary"

Comment: contentType(MediaType.****) не надо указывать разве?